# Can Dokan split out sales tax into a separate transaction?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, marketplace, dokan

We are currently running a marketplace using Dokan where all vendor/buyer transactions are handled by PayPal Express Checkout. Most of our user base is in California where tax rates vary between cities. WooCommerce tax settings are in place based on shipping address, but currently this gets tacked onto the money that the vendor receives, so they pocket the sales tax while we foot the bill out of our own pocket.

We have tried using the [PayPal for WooCommerce Multi-Account Management](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-woocommerce-multi-account-management/) plugin to send a flat percentage to our own PayPal account to deal with sales tax, but since this only allows a set percentage it is not suitable for California's infinite variety of tax rates, plus it incurs another transaction fee.

Is there any feasible way we can add sales tax to the total for the buyer, pay the vendor their share, and send the sales tax to our own PayPal account (with minimal or even no 2nd transaction fee)? If this is not possible with PayPal, is there any other payment provider that could do this & which could slot into Dokan with minimal hacking?

Answer (score 0):

If you [onboard every seller for multi-party payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/seller-onboarding/before-payment/#link-onboardsellersbeforepayment) including the third_party_details [feature PARTNER_FEE](https://developer.paypal.com/api/partner-referrals/v2/#definition-rest_endpoint_feature) (a necessary initial setup) -- then, for every transaction you can pass amount details including all item and tax information for display/transaction record purposes, and additionally include the tax amount you wish to collect as part of the partner_fee being deducted from what the seller receives and sent to you as the facilitator. [This answer goes into more detail on that last part.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70827816/paypal-capturing-taxes-and-fees-on-an-order/70964910#70964910)

Comment: This is a very helpful answer - if we can get this integrated with Dokan then it might be the only feasible way forwards. Thanks for this.